# How to delete duplicated clients based on value in datetime column in Data Frame in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have DataFrame in Python Pandas like below:

```
date_col   | ID  | Phone
-----------|-----|--------
2020-05-17 | 111 | Apple
2020-06-11 | 111 | Sony
2021-12-28 | 222 | Sony
```

As you can see ID "111" is duplicated and I need to do that when ID is duplicated I need to take row with the latest date from column "date_col" (this col is in format datetime64).
So as a result I need something like below becase ID "111" is duplicated but date 2020-06-11 is higher than 2020-05-17:

```
date_col   | ID  | Phone
-----------|-----|--------
2020-06-11 | 111 | Sony
2021-12-28 | 222 | Sony
```

How can I do that in Python Pandas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```py
df = df.sort_values(by="date_col").drop_duplicates(subset="ID", keep="last")
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
    date_col   ID Phone
1 2020-06-11  111  Sony
2 2021-12-28  222  Sony
```